# How to get the domain extension from a URL string?

Tags: java, string, substring

How to find the type of website using the URL below.

- .com – commercial website
- .org – organization website
- .lk – Sri Lankan website

Example: *input* > stackoverflow.com
*Output* > It's a Commercial website.

I don't know how to get the last 3 sub-strings.

Comment: Use split, like `String[] tokens = input.split("\\.")`. It's the last token.

Comment: Does this also include subdirectories such as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one helps:

```
public class DomainFinder {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String url = "stackoverflow.org";
    String [] word = url.split("\\.");
    String domain = word[word.length -1];
    switch(domain){
        case "com" : System.out.println("Commercial");
                    break;
        case "edu" : System.out.println("Educational");
                    break;
        case "org" : System.out.println("Organization");
                    break;
        default: System.out.println("Not a valid domain");
                    break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map to hold all the `top level domains` you're interested in. Then split on `.` as was suggested in the comments by `Elliot Frisch`

```
String[] sites = {
        "stackoverflow.org",
        "someUniversity.edu",
        "bigSales.com",
        "USCapitol.gov"
};
Map<String, String> domainMap = Map.of(
        "com", "Commercial website",
        "org", "Organization website",
        "edu", "Educational website");

for (String site : sites) {
    String[] domainHierarchy = site.split("\\.");
    String domain = domainHierarchy[domainHierarchy.length - 1];
    String webSite = domainMap.getOrDefault(domain,
            "No site available for `%s` domain".formatted(domain));
    System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", domain, webSite);
}
```

prints

```
org -> Organization website
edu -> Educational website
com -> Commercial website
gov -> No site available for `gov` domain
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`URI(str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI-java.lang.String-) to extract the domain name and then use the [`String#substring (beginIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) to extract the text after the last `.` in it.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        Map<String, String> domain = Map.of(
                "com", "commercial website",
                "org", "organization website",
                "lk", "Sri Lankan website");

        // Test
        String[] testURLs = {
                "https://stackoverflow.com",
                "https://stackoverflow.com/questions",
                "https://srilankacricket.lk",
                "https://srilankacricket.lk/",
                "https://www.wikipedia.org/",
                "https://www.gov.uk/"
        };
        for (String s : testURLs) {
            String domainName = new URI(s).getHost();
            System.out.printf("%s --> %s%n", s, domain.getOrDefault(domainName.substring(domainName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1), "Unknown"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
https://stackoverflow.com --> commercial website
https://stackoverflow.com/questions --> commercial website
https://srilankacricket.lk --> Sri Lankan website
https://srilankacricket.lk/ --> Sri Lankan website
https://www.wikipedia.org/ --> organization website
https://www.gov.uk/ --> Unknown
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/AdSeBL)

**Alternatively,**

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZUYwSV/1), `(?<=\.)\p{L}+(?=\/|$)` which can be explained as follows:

- `(?<=\.)`: Preceded by a `.` character - using positive lookbehind here
- `\p{L}+`: One or more letter(s)
- `(?=\/|$)`: Followed by either `/` or end of line - using positive lookahead here

You can learn more about lookaround from [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "(?<=\\.)\\p{L}+(?=\\/|$)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Map<String, String> domain = Map.of(
                "com", "commercial website",
                "org", "organization website",
                "lk", "Sri Lankan website");

        // Test
        Stream.of(
                "https://stackoverflow.com",
                "https://stackoverflow.com/questions",
                "https://srilankacricket.lk",
                "https://srilankacricket.lk/",
                "https://www.wikipedia.org/",
                "https://www.gov.uk/"
        ).forEach(s -> {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if (matcher.find())
                System.out.printf("%s --> %s%n", s, domain.getOrDefault(matcher.group(),"Unknown"));
        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
https://stackoverflow.com --> commercial website
https://stackoverflow.com/questions --> commercial website
https://srilankacricket.lk --> Sri Lankan website
https://srilankacricket.lk/ --> Sri Lankan website
https://www.wikipedia.org/ --> organization website
https://www.gov.uk/ --> Unknown
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/YHTBpp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *[String#lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int))* method.

```java
String string = "stackoverflow.com";
String type
  = switch (string.substring(string.lastIndexOf('.'))) {
        case ".com" -> "commercial";
        case ".org" -> "organization";
        case ".lk" -> "Sri Lankan";
        default -> "unknown";
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.endsWith()` method:

```java
public static String checkWebsite(String url) {
    if (url.endsWith(".com"))
        return "Commercial website";
    if (url.endsWith(".org"))
        return "Organization website";
    if (url.endsWith(".lk"))
        return "Sri Lankan website";
    return "Unknown website";
}
```